# How to send an email to multiple email addresses in the database using Postal in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, postal

I'm trying to find a solution on how to send an email to **multiple** Hospital email addresses depending on which orders are linked to the Delivery that the change is being made on - using [Postal](http://aboutcode.net/postal/).

So for a bit of context, I wish to send the same email to all the Hospitals that have orders linked to a delivery. So upon editing a delivery, (to change the `status` for example), an email must be sent to **ALL** the hospitals that have Orders in that Delivery.

The issue is that a Delivery can have many orders and not necessarily just one, and because of that, I'm not sure how to target all the email addresses of all the hospitals that have Orders in that specific Delivery.

Also, a Hospital is only linked to an Order and an Order is linked to a Delivery - and the only way to access the hospital's email is from the `Hospital` table. Which means I have to go through the `Order` table and then to the `Hospital` table.

How would I go about doing this? I'm still pretty new to MVC, so I will appreciate all the help I can get.

I'm doing this in the **POST** of my **Edit Method** in the **Delivery Controller** because I only wish to send an email from there after an Edit has been made. Hence why I call it after the `savechanges()`.

These lines`Order order = db.Orders.Where(o => o.OrderID == order.DeliveryID).FirstOrDefault();` and `Hospital hospital = db.Hospitals.(h => h.HospitalID == order.HospitalID);` are just my attempts. They don't work, and are not part of the original code.

If there is any additional code required, please let me know and I'll add it to the question!

**Models**

**Delivery**

```
public class Delivery
{

    public int DeliveryID { get; set; }

    public int DriverID { get; set; }

    public virtual Driver Driver { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

**Hospital**

```
public class Hospital
{
    public int HospitalID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

**Order**

```
   public class Order
    {
        public int OrderID { get; set; }

        public int HospitalID { get; set; }

        public int? DeliveryID { get; set; }}

        public virtual Hospital Hospital { get; set; }

        public virtual Delivery Delivery { get; set; }
    }
```

**DeliveryVM viewModel**

```
public class DeliveryVM
{
    public int? ID { get; set; } 

    public int DriverID { get; set; }

    public SelectList DriverList { get; set; }

    public List<OrderVM> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

**Delivery Controller POST method:**

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(DeliveryVM model)
    {

        // Get the data model based on the ID of the view model
        Delivery delivery = db.Deliverys.Find(model.ID);
        // Map the view model properties to the data model
        delivery.DriverID = model.DriverID;
         ....

        db.SaveChanges();

            //Email
            Order order = db.Orders.Where(o => o.OrderID == order.DeliveryID).FirstOrDefault(); // I tried this but it didn't work. It was just an attempt
            Hospital hospital = db.Hospitals.(h => h.HospitalID == order.HospitalID); // I was going to use this to retrieve the hospitalIDs linked to the Order? Don't know if thats correct
            dynamic email = new Email("Example");
            email.ID = delivery.DeliveryID;
            email.To = hospital.Email; // this is where you set the email you are sending to. 
            email.Send();
            //End
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

**Note**

- I  removed **a lot** of code from the Delivery Edit Method for readability, so if necessary I can add that to the question as well.

Comment: Please use `inline code` for inline code, not to highlight random terms. It decreases readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to do something like

```
//Email
var emailQuery = from o in db.Orders
    from h in o.Hospital
    where o.DeliveryID = model.ID 
//i'm not sure where this order comes from but if you 
//don't really have that then you may need to use your DeliverVM instead
    select new { Email = h.Email };

var emails = emailQuery.ToList();

dynamic email = new Email("Example");
email.ID = order.DeliveryID;
email.To = emails.Join(";"); // you can have more that one email because you have multiple orders
email.Send();
```

Comment: I'm getting an error on this line `h in o.Hospital`  its saying it failed to `SelectMany`, any ideas?

Comment: This line is in my DeliveryVM viewmodel  `public List<OrderVM> Orders { get; set; }` would that make a difference?

Comment: I changed it to use your view model variable instead, but that assumes that the ID there is the DeliveryID for your orders.

Comment: back to my first comment again. it has an issue with `o.Hospital` - its saying it failed in the call to `SelectMany`.

Comment: I managed to fix that issue, however, now a new issue. The email function doesn't recognize the two emails and as emails and refuses to send. I think its because of the way the array is displaying the email addresses? `{email1@example.com};{email2@example.com}`

Comment: I fixed it, and I made the changes to your answer that worked for me. Thanks for setting me on the right track.

Comment: Seems like the [Postal documentation](http://aboutcode.net/postal/email-headers.html) suggests to seperate email addresses with "," instead of ";".